# How to auto-remove redundant surface pieces that are closer to the viewpoint

Tags: blender, mesh, 3d-reconstruction, 3d-modelling, meshlab

Assume I have two parts of 3D mesh, which needs to be fused into a integrated 3D model. After fusion, some facets that are not used for the closure of the 3D model are **redundant**, and I want to **remove them automatically**. I'd like know if some **filters in existing softwares**(e.g., meshlab, blender, etc.) could do this job, or are there some specific **algorithms** handling this problem?

Below is an ugly free-hand sketch of my mind, hope that it could help understanding my intension:

PS: not sure if this question is suitable for S.O. or superuser.com, I put it here because the TAG suggestion is more plentiful ;)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How to do it in Maya:

1. Make both of the objects closed geometry, meaning leaving no open holes on the mesh. You may use the "fill hole" function in maya.
2. Make sure there is no history node connected to the objects. (search maya delete history)
3. Select the objects, and run Boolean operation (intersection) in Maya.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a *fully*-automatic way, but a few step in blender should achieve what you want.

1. Position mesh pieces as desired.
2. Use *Mesh->Faces->Intersect (Knife)* - this will cut the mesh where the pieces intersect with each other.
3. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to deselect everything and with the mouse over an unwanted extreme press <kbd>L</kbd> to select the mesh connected to it and then <kbd>X</kbd>*->Vertices* to delete them.
4. Repeat 3 for all unwanted sections.
5. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything then <kbd>W</kbd>*->Remove Doubles* to merge the vertices close to each other to join the remaining mesh into one solid piece.